# Prisma how to create a model when database table has hyphen in it?

Tags: javascript, mysql, reactjs, next.js, prisma

i have tables in my database with hyphen, like "user-cars". I cannot change the name to "user_cars". Is there a way to name the model as "user_cars" but make it reference the "user-cars" table? I tried `@@map("user_cars")`, but it didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the docs, you'd map the model to the underlying table name. You tried `user_cars` but did you try `user-cars`? If your table name is `user-cars` then you should map that to your model like:

```js
model UserCar {
  // Fields

  @@map("user-cars")
}
```

https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-schema/names-in-underlying-database

Their example is:

> However, you can still choose Comment as the name of the model (e.g.
> to follow the naming convention) without renaming the underlying
> comments table in the database by using the @@map attribute:

```js
model Comment {
  // Fields

  @@map("comments")
}
```

The model names typically follow the convention where the underlying table is plural, and the model name itself is singular. Ideally you should use `UserCar` as the model name instead of `user_cars`.

https://www.prisma.io/docs/reference/api-reference/prisma-schema-reference#naming-conventions

I hope that helps!